# error : cannot find symbol java for inner class

Tags: java, sockets, compiler-errors

I am teaching myself socket programming using `java`, and I am encountering this problem while compiling . I have declared an inner class `Book` inside the main class `library_s` and the compiler is not recognizing the variable `Status` defined in the class `Book`. I am using `Book` as a `static class` because I read that enums only exist in static classes. I wanted an analog to `"struct"` in C because I am only familiar with that. I have looked at various other similar errors,, but none of them are helpful. Please help out. Thank you!

```
public class library_s extends Thread{

private ServerSocket lib_server;

LinkedList<Book> library = new LinkedList<Book>();

//constructor

  public library_s(int port) throws IOException{
    lib_server = new ServerSocket(port);
    lib_server.setSoTimeout(10000);
    }

public void run(){

Socket server = lib_server.accept();
    System.out.println("Connected to " + server.getRemoteSocketAddress());

    DataInputStream is = new DataInputStream(server.getInputStream());

    DataOutputStream os = new DataOutputStream(server.getOutputStream());

    for(library b : library){
      if(b.BookName == is.readUTF(){
           if(b.Status == FORISSUE){
         //enter rest of the body here
       }
      }

     }

   public static class Book{
    public String BookName;
    public static enum Status {FORISSUE, ISSUED, RENEW, RESERVE};

    public Book(String bn){
            this.BookName = bn;
            this.Status =   FORISSUE;
    }
}

public static void main(String [] args){
int port = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
try{
    Thread t = new library_s(port);
    t.start();
} catch (IOException e){
    e.printStackTrace();
   }
  }
 }
}
```

The compiler gives error

```
library_s.java:64: error: cannot find symbol
    if(b.Status == FORISSUE){           
        ^
symbol:   variable Status
location: variable b of type Book
library_s.java:64: error: cannot find symbol
    if(b.Status == FORISSUE){           
                   ^
```

Comment: share original code.

Answer (score 1):

You declared the `enum` inside class `Book` so it's not recognized from outside (other classes).
In order to fix it, either declare the enum inside `library_s` or outside `Book` the same way you would do with any other class in the package, or, if you want to keep that enum inside class `Book` you can access it using:

```
Book.Status.FORISSUE
```

Comment: It's public enum. why can't access outside.

Comment: First, you *can* access it - see the last part of my answer. Second, this is a public which is a member of class Book, you should consider it like any other static member of class `Book`.

Comment: there is no variable `this.Status` in class `Book`

Comment: @user3218114 correct. In order yo have `this.Status` you have to declare it as an instance variable in class `Book`, for example: `private Status status;` (you can add it right after you declare the enum)

Comment: @user3218114 that is because `Status` is a type, not a variable. Create a new file with only the enum in it and remove it from the location it is now. Then you will see that you have no `Status` variable in your `Book` class.

Answer (score 1):

You have declared a type `Status`, but not a variable of that type.

In your `Book` class:

```
private Status status;

public Book( ... )
{
    // ...
    this.status = Status.FORISSUE;
}
```

Outside of the class, you have to use `Book.Status` since it is a nested type. Eg.

```
if( b.status = Book.Status.FORISSUE ) { ... }
```

Comment: Should it be Book.Status.FORISSUE or Book.status.FORISSUE ?

Comment: `Status`, with the capital letter, you are referring to the type. So when you want to use an enum value you use that. When you want to refer to the variable you use the lower case.

Comment: It still says it cannot find symbol `Status`

Answer (score 1):

`Status` is a nested `enum` type inside `Book` class, not a field. You should be declaring a field of type `Status`. The assignment in your constructor is also suspicious. You are assigning a value of type `Status` to enum itself. That wouldn't compile.

Have a variable declared in your `Book` class as:

```
private Status status;
```

... and use it like:

```
if (b.status == Book.Status.FORISSUE)
```

Apart from that, you've numerous other compilation errors. Your `if` block as below is missing closing parenthesis:

```
if(b.BookName == is.readUTF()
```

Moreover, you're using `==` to compare string, which is not a compilation error, but functionally that will most certainly fail.

Another thing is, you don't need to declare your `enum` `static`. Nested enums are by default `static` only.

Lastly, please follow Java naming convention. It is so hard to read your code right now. Class name should start with UpperCase alphabets, and variable name with lowerCase alphabets.

> I am using Book as a static class because I read that enums only exist in static classes.

Where did you read that? Please quote your sources. You can declare an `enum` in a non-static class too.

Comment: Thank you. Where do I declare a field of type Status. as you mentioned. I am new to java, so didn't know about naming convention. Will fix it.

Comment: @tina On what type are you trying to access it? Declare it inside that type.

Comment: Inside a method in the parent class. Okay.

Comment: Will the equals() method work fine for comparing the strings?

Comment: `equals()` method are used to compare Strings in java. So,yes,for sure!

Comment: I used it like

if (b.status == Book.Status.FORISSUE)

but it still says "cannot find symbol : Status"

Comment: @tina I asked on what type you are accessing it, not where you're accessing it. You're accessing it on variable of type `Book`. So declare that field in `Book` class.